# The code causes a malfunction in some phones and works on the emulator. Is there an explanation?

Tags: java, dialog

- This is the error in the Google Play Store

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
>   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked (WindowManagerGlobal.java:572)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:476)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate (WindowManagerImpl.java:144)
>   at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog (Dialog.java:389)
>   at android.app.Dialog.dismiss (Dialog.java:371)
>   at com.master.azkarmorningevening.LoadingDialog.dismissDialog (LoadingDialog.java)
>   at com.master.azkarmorningevening.-$$Lambda$hxi6xW-58LrFqQAbkmexCKkt5eY.run(lambda)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:236)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8060)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:656)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:967)
> ```

- The class that i create Dialog

  ```
  class LoadingDialog {
        Activity activity;
        private AlertDialog dialog;
        LoadingDialog(Activity myActivity){
            activity = myActivity;
        }


        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        void StartLoadingAlertDialog(){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
           AlertDialog.Builder(activity,R.style.full_sereen_mood);

            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash,null));
            builder.setCancelable(false);

            dialog = builder.create();


            dialog.show();
        }


        void dismissDialog(){
                dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
  ```
- i get function from class LoandinDailog
- with Handler

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LoadingDialog loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(MainActivity.this);
        loadingDialog.StartLoadingAlertDialog();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(loadingDialog::dismissDialog,3000);



    }
  ```

  }
- Make Style for Dialog for class LoadingDialog
- To define some properties

> parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
>
> ```
>     <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
>     <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
>     <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
>     <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
>     <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
>     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
> </style>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** You need to place the part below inside onResume()

```
  LoadingDialog loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(MainActivity.this);
  loadingDialog.StartLoadingAlertDialog();
  Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
  handler.postDelayed(loadingDialog::dismissDialog,3000);
```

With that done, the splash screen will appear every time the UI thread resumes, which is going to be annoying, so you'll need to have a flag that tells you whether the splash screen was already shown, or not, and check for that condition before you execute that block of code inside onResume()

**Longer answer:** You need to watch some videos on youtube from Google IO about the Activity lifecycle. Those Android fundamentals are very important and they can not be fully explained in a page or two.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEKNi1JOrNs

Comment: Thanks for your response. Glad to receive your answer. This code is a replacement for the splash screen that appears for three seconds with every start of the home page. I am asking why this error message comes up in Google Console for some devices and not all devices cause the same error. I put the code in the beginning so that it works only when creating the activity

Comment: @قناةالرياضيات, That part, I do not know.